# MATLAB Slider GUI with Background While Loop to Control Feedback Servo Motors

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback, servo

I am attempting to implement a *servo motor with feedback control* program in MATLAB for multiple servo motors. The objective is to read servo(s) analog output, compare with a user value from slider bar(s), write the new position to the servo, and continue to write or monitor analog output to ensure servo maintains last user value. I am having trouble because I cannot figure out the optimal flow to always keep the GUI open and accepting user values while a *while* loop runs in the background.    Below is the general structure that I would like the code to output:

```
test_gui %calls GUI figure with slider bar
```

GUI window with Slider bar pops up

```
%Callback for when user slides bar
function slider(i)_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 % hObject    handle to slider1 (see GCBO)

 load('user.mat'); %Load previous user input
 sze=size(user,1);
 user(sze+1,1)=get(hObject,'Value'); %Add new user input to previous input
 save('user.mat','user') %Save variable to be accessed by outer loop
```

'user' is passed into a continuous while loop that writes servo position

```
while user ~= 'c'  %Continue to run until close window callback

 load('user.mat'); %load user input from callback

 Write_Servoi(a,user(end,:),add,speed,pinin,myServo) %Writes to servo(s) based on last input, allows servo(s) to maintain position if torqued out of position

end
```

During this while loop, I would like the user to be able to continuously change the slider and send this slider value into the while loop to be written to the servo. However, I cannot figure out how to update **user** when in the while loop.

If anyone has any ideas on how to get this to work, please let me know. I would greatly appreciate any help. I am open to changing the structure, as long as the objectives above are satisfied.

Robert

Answer (score 0):

To update the user variable, you'll need to make sure it is properly loaded. Calling `load` with no output does not always load your variable into the function workspace.

Instead of `load('user.mat');`, you'll need to load your file as a structure and then retrieve your variable from the structure. To accomplish this, do the following:

`s=load('user.mat');
 user=s.user;`

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, this wasn't quite the issue. I figured out that using the getappdata(0,'variable') and setappdata('0','variable',variable) was the best solution.